# jQuery Tabs Causing Postback Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an app with JQuery tabs to display all of my content. Everything works but when the user selects the logout button, it posts back and I get the following error

```
   The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. 
   Description: 
   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.     
   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\627a9c02\870fb5b3\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.lrjt4utr.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. ]
System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +77
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +147

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Port: 
Referer: http://localhost:1237/default.aspx
Path: /default.aspx
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
ViewState: /wEPDwUKMjA4ODU5NDYwMWQYAgUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgMFNWN0bDAwJE1haW5Db250ZW50JEhlYWRMb2dpblZpZXckSGVhZExvZ2luU3RhdHVzJGN0bDAxBTVjdGwwMCRNYWluQ29udGVudCRIZWFkTG9naW5WaWV3JEhlYWRMb2dpblN0YXR1cyRjdGwwMwUmY3RsMDAkTWFpbkNvbnRlbnQkTG9naW5Vc2VyJFJlbWVtYmVyTWUFH2N0bDAwJE1haW5Db250ZW50JEhlYWRMb2dpblZpZXcPD2QCAWQ32uen3eiriKYlE49WCOp7gXtn08ext+/697YeD7DxzQ==,/wEPDwUJMzg1OTg5NDIxZGQnnUqYiBZZWyHLBN0PExZlAOJfaAuIjtM4PahUembbmA==]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +235
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +251
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +106
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8431
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +253
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\627a9c02\870fb5b3\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.lrjt4utr.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

My code for the default page is here

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CCIQARewrite.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">



     $(document).ready(function () {

           $("#tabs").tabs();

         });
    </script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CCLogo.jpg" />
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server"  ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                    [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" /> ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        </div>  

<div class="clear">
<div id="tabs">


                  <ul>

                    <li><a href="My Audits.aspx" id="MyAuditsTab">My Audits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="My Claims.aspx">My Claims</a></li>
                    <%--<li><a href="Reports.aspx">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Maintenance.aspx">Maintenance</a></li>--%>

                  </ul>




        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div id="login" style="display:none">


    <h2>
        Log In
    </h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your username and password.
        <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.
        </p>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry">  </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
       </div>
        </form>


    </asp:Content>
```

I know the tabs are related to this error because when I remove the Jquery creating the tabs, it posts back without error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing `__doPostBack();` yourself, trigger a `click` event on the logout button, which will instruct asp.net to raise a postback in a proper way.

```
$('#yourlogoutselector').trigger('click'); //didn't find your logout button
```

Comment: I am using the default post actions for the login status control, the __doPostBack() is from the modal dialog, I'll remove that part since it isn't really relevant to the question